# Eclipse live error checking disabled

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, syntax-error, eclipse-cdt

Few days ago I had to reinstall all my Linux system, and I also had to reinstall Eclipse CDT as I used to work with it since few weeks.

Unfortunately, since then I do not have live error checking anymore... and I miss it ;)

---

If I create a new Hello World C++ project *(New / C++ Project / Hello World C++ project)* and then add some errors like calling a method from an nonexistent class or adding any undefined or untyped variable, well Eclispe doesn't underline and report them as it was doing before I had to reinstall it all.

I searched stackoverflow, and tried to deactivate/reactive *"Build automatically"* without any change. I also verified that the project path is included in the project sources *(Project properties / C-C++ general / Path  and Symbols / Source Location)* but as it already was, it didn't solved the problem.

When I "Build All" the errors are well reported in the *"Problems view"*, and then when I fix one problem and save the file, the error disappear from the Problem view, but then if I add another problem and save, nothing is reported until I build again. Even errors turned to comments still remains underlined until the next *"build all"*.

Do you have any idea to help me reactivate this feature ?

I was under Eclipse Linux 3.5 and I now use Eclipse Linux 3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the Eclipse package: [Eclipse C/C++ IDE Indigo SR-1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigosr1) with Eclipse Platform 3.7.1 and that fixed the problem.

So I guess, there was a problem with the 3.7.0 currently provided by the Ubuntu Software Center.

With this new version all is Ok by default.